# Как как реализовать автозаполнение полей модели Django?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

eсть модель PhoneBook. Как сделать(реализовать) связанную модель алфавитного указателя по первой букве. Что бы в автоматические создавалась категория(первая буква имени) и в последующем в эту категорию добавлялись контакты, у которых первая буква имени равна категории.

```
class PhoneBook(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Имя")
surname = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Фамилия")
company = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Компания", blank=True)
number = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name='Телефон')
comment = models.TextField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Комментарий', blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="e-mail", blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['surname']

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.name.title()} {self.surname.title()}'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('number_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

В модели Alphabet нужно реализовать автозаполнение полей.

```
class Alphabet(models.Model):

letter = models.CharField(max_length=1)  # Буква
contact = models.ForeignKey(PhoneBook)  # Добавление контакта автоматически
```

Что бы получилось как на скрине. Заполняешь форму, а алфавитный указать подставляется автоматически.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему код в вопросе в  виде  скриншота? исправьте вопрос, чтобы код был в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: Поправил, вопрос)